# Problem regarding gvfs and symlink

Tags: permissions, samba, libreoffice, symbolic-link, gvfs

I have a samba share that is serving some LibreOffice templates and a tree to store generated `.odt`s. As long as I try to open these documents using file manager all is well. I have written some management GUI's in OpenOffice Basic that works with both the templates and the document store. Those are accessed over a symlink in the filesystem as my macros are not aware of the gvfs story.

In short:
I made a symlink from the `gvfs` created mount

```
/run/user/USERID/gvfs/smb-share\server\=myserver\,share\=myshare/
```

to

```
/mnt/myappdata
```

As long as I open a `.odt` file using the file manager, it works fine. As soon as I try to open the same file over the symbolic link `/mnt/myappdata;`, LibreOffice reports the file is locked by unknown user. I wrote this program 15 years ago and have been using it over the years without any problems on Windows, Mac and Linux across, since Ubuntu 19 this problem shows up.

I have already tried connecting to the file repo using SSH instead, but the results are the same. Permissions on the directories that hold symlink are adequate.